# How to extract images from a scan. How do I find images inside an image?

Tags: c#-4.0, wia

I made a scanner program that scans pictures from my scanner ADF using WIA. It works fine but I want to be able to do multiple images scanned from the flatbed as well.

How do I tell where an image is on the flatbed though? I need to know where to crop the scanned image, but without knowing where the images are located in the scanned image, I can't crop it.

I have searched google but everything I'm finding is for comparing an image, or seeing if the image exists in another image and such. That's of course not what I'm looking for. I just want to be able to find the location of any and all image/s in the flatbed so I can loop through and save each one individually.

The program is written in c#.

Answer (score 1):

Algorithm:
It is possible to construct a filter using edge detectors that will select individual images from a set of non-overlapping rectangles.

I would take the following approach: Obtain a list of edges with an edge detector. Filter those into sets of edges that intersect and form a loop and the count of edges in that loop is 4. Purge any loops that occur inside another loop. You may also want to remove edges that have a low quality (you're looking for the straight lines of rectangles, so the edges you want should be easy to spot).

Then you have a list of loops of borders of images, so you can do some basic processing (bilinear affine blit) to convert out any misalignment and output them to file.

Possible Library:
I'd look at opencv.net, http://code.google.com/p/opencvdotnet/ .